# I need openGl 2.0 but my graphic card support 1.5

Tags: opengl, webgl

I want to start with my webGL project and minimal require is my graphic card support openGL 2.0.
Problem exist because i have intel laptop with integrated intel 965 graphic media accelerator and driver is up to date and it support openGL 1.5.

Is there any solution how to update my graphic carf to support 2.0? Is this possible?

Comment: this question belongs to superuser.com I would think

Comment: Graphics card capabilities ultimately come from the hardware, you can't upgrade the hardware. (You need to get new hardware.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Okay. just stay patient actually because ANGLE is coming. It seems to me that your hardware is able to run directX 9 and ANGLE is a project from google to allow webgl support from directX. But as the others say, you can't upgrade opengl drivers just like that. Or you could try MESA in the firefox build.

For more information, see Learningwebgl.com.

Comment: I has already done that but my webGL demo wasn't worked because the newest version of mozilla (Minefield) isn't bugs free. I download older version an everything works fine. If someone have same problem older version can donwload here:
http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/firefox/nightly/3.7a4-candidates/build1/
Thx

Answer (score 3):

Sadly no. With a little more effort you can still develop against opengl 2.0 but you'll need to use another machine (or just buy a better graphics card) to test anything 2.0 specific (pixel shading for instance).

Ok, that's not entirely true. You could download the mesa library and compile it for win32 and get some of the opengl 2.0 functionality emulated in a software renderer but it would be very slow.

Answer (score 3):

It's possible that updating drivers might help some, but probably won't make that jump. Otherwise, you could use something like [Mesa3D](http://www.mesa3d.org/), which does the rendering in software. It can be slow, but does support up through OpenGL 2.1 (including shaders), if memory serves.

Answer (score 2):

If there's no other way, you could try http://www.mesa3d.org/ . I haven't followed this project for quite some time, but apparently they currently provide OpenGL 2.1 software rendering.

Answer (score 1):

I just updated drivers my HP 6710b with Mobile Intel 965 Express Chipset -- and now WebGL is working in Firefox 4 RC1!

I put instructions on [this site](http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebook-HP-ProBook-Compaq-Slate/igxprd32-display-driver-has-stopped-working-normally/m-p/1154658).

It is not pretty but it works!

Answer (score 0):

angleproject is your best bet. Check out which exact 965 card you have from here (search for 'intel gma' in wikipedia), which also lists the OpenGL support version for these cards. It might take a couple of months though before you can use angleproject to accelerate your WebGL application.

I have a slightly newer 4500MHD, and I have the same problem. WebGL works on Firefox 3.7a4, but fails in the later versions a5 and a6. I had to use the latest drivers from Intel which claim to support OpenGL 2.0. The Microsoft drivers don't ship with OpenGL support.

I have reported a issue in the Firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=570474. It looks like support for Intel cards might be fixed by the time the releases are in beta.